# using oracle to_date function without a format mask

Tags: oracle, to-date

this may be a dumb question however.. I have these two selects: 1st one returns a result, while 2nd gives me a not a valid month error. I can't seem to figure out why..

```
select to_date('09-12-14','dd-mm-rr') - to_date('01/january/2007') from dual;
select to_date('09-12-14','dd-mm-rr') - to_date('01-01-2007') from dual;
```

Tnx in advance

Comment: `Select sysdate from dual;` will have the same format as that of your `locale-specific nls settings`. Using that format won't need you to provide format mask. However, be advised, it is strongly recommended to use an explicit format mask to avoid any nls format mismatch.

Comment: i always use format masks for to_date, to be safe; this question is related to a oca test question actually and i was trying to understand it. 
it was originally like this: dates are stored in the default dd-mm-rr format. choose what statement gives the right output and the statement: select sysdate - to_date('01/january/2007') from dual;

Comment: The question you quoted from oca itself is wrong. **Date is never stored in the format we see it. It is only to display for human beings to interpret easily. Date is stored internally by Oracle in 7 bytes.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't specify a format mask, Oracle will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting (and some predefined masks) to determine the date time format mask.

Apparently your server settings support the first format, and not the second. Therefore it is better to always specify your format mask.

Comment: rewrote my whole comment as i didn't manage to edit it on time. after some more research i found out that when not using a format mask oracle can convert automatically strings like DD-MON-YYYY, DD-MON-YY, DD-MONTH-YYYY, DD-MONTH-YY.
what i don't understand is why it let me subtract dates in different formats..
the question is from a oca test as im preparing for my exam. it was originally like this: dates are stored in the default dd-mm-rr format. choose what statement gives the right output and the statement: select sysdate - to_date('01/january/2007') from dual;

Comment: nvm, i selected each of them from dual and they do match. thanks for your answer!